# How to show thumbnails of images stored on Google Drive on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, images, firefox, thumbnail

I have a Google spreadsheet that contains hyperlinks to files stored on my Google Drive using a `HYPERLINK` formula.

Opening the spreadsheet and hovering the cursor over the link when logged in my GSuite account, I can see a thumbnail preview and that's pretty neat (if you feel lucky, [try yourself on this example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wa7mR3IgHMgj-VatAe0id9x2oM7-PFrMXyH7tLasbJo/edit?pli=1#gid=0))!

[image: thumbnail preview]

However, this doesn't happen for my collaborators in the same GSuite org, and indeed if I open the same spreadsheet with another account with similar access rights (on the spreadsheet and on the image) I don't see any thumbnail preview.

Not seeing thumbnails occurs on Firefox 77.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10 and Linux 5.6.15-arch1-1 but also Edge 83.0.478.50 on Win 10 **in incognito mode, when not logged in**. The reproducible example above was created with my personal Gmail account. For this example specifically, the cat image is shared with the option "Anyone on the internet with this link can view". See here for an example:

[image]

You can try the example I took the screenshot of [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wa7mR3IgHMgj-VatAe0id9x2oM7-PFrMXyH7tLasbJo/edit?pli=1#gid=0). Is this feature currently available on selected accounts only, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your "environment" (operative system name and version, type of Internet connection (wired / wi-fi, etc, domestic, work/school, public )  name and version of web browsers used, if you were browsing in regular / private mode, if you have extensions, if your spreadsheet was created with common Google Account (usually @gmail.com ) of if you are using a G Suite account, if the images are shared with anyone on the web with the link o publicly on the web...

Comment: I suggest you to try using "Publicly in the web" instead of "anyone with this link"

Comment: Does the images changes over time (upload new versions while keeping the same link)?

Comment: No, once the files and link are generated they stay the same, i.e. I don't upload new versions with the same name on GDrive. I do add more entries to the spreadsheet and new files to GDrive though.

Comment: Have you considered to add the "thumbnails" in a cell next to the link instead or rely on the "hovering bubble"?

Comment: Yes! It could be possible with `IMAGE()` I believe, right? It would add a bit too much clutter, but that may be a workaround indeed! Liked hovering better though :(

Comment: I'm afraid that using `=IMAGE()` might have the same "problem", if so, you could right click the image to convert it as an "in cell image"... or use Google Apps Script to do that "automatically"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109495/discussion-between-davide-fiocco-and-ruben).

Answer (score 1):

As this feature is available to all accounts, you *are missing something* <s>but *we* can't tell you exactly what</s>: **some Google Editors**<sup>1</sup>  **features:**

1. are only available in Chrome.
2. requires to be signed in a Google Account
3. requires a G Suite account

Please bear in mind that you could send your feedback directly to Google through Google Feedback <sup>2</sup>

NOTES:

1. Docs, Drawings, Forms, Sheets, Slides
2. You could send your feedback directly from the spreadsheet. I think that it will be nice if you include a summary and a link to your question.

---

<sup>I followed the link in your question using Windows 10 64-bit, single language (Spanish), Chrome, signed-in, it works. I did the same on Firefox, when not signed-in it didn't work, but when signed-in it works.</sup>

---

Related

- [Google Drive doesn't show thumbnails in grid view](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/81116/88163)
- [Is there a "best way" to send Google feedback?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82708/88163)
- [What information about me is visible with shareable links?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/111165/88163)

Comment: OK it can work in Firefox though, it does when I sign in my GSuite account (proof: https://imgur.com/a/XngaKtd) so it's still puzzling to me. Nice footnote :)

Comment: @DavideFiocco Updated my answer.